# setactiveitem works only once

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

my problem is i have 3 view files and one controller.

the following is the code for 3 button tap events.

```
onb1:function(){

    Ext.Viewport.remove(Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem(), true);

    Ext.Viewport.add({xtype:'second',height:'30%',style:'background:red'}).show();

},

onb3:function(){

    Ext.Viewport.remove(Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem(), true);

    Ext.Viewport.add({xtype:'main'}).show();

},

onb2:function(){

    Ext.Viewport.remove(Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem(), true);

    Ext.Viewport.add({xtype:'third',height:'60%',style:'background:orange'}).show();

}
```

it works only once.

tell me any solution...

Answer (score 1):

The activeItem is automatically set the first time. After that you have to set it yourself. There is also no need to call show(). Should work like this:

```
    Ext.Viewport.add(someView);     
    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(someView);
```

Comment: thanks,but my application have fill with id references and i will get this error Ext.Component#constructor] Registering a component with a id (`first`) which has already been used. Please ensure the existing component has been destroyed (`Ext.Component#destroy()`.
with out changing id any solution

Comment: Can you post the code of your component, too? Furthermore, it is recommended to use itemIds instead of using assigned ids. More info over here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-id

Answer (score 1):

The reason is, this line of code:

`Ext.Viewport.remove(Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem(), true);`

will remove your component, then destroy it.

Perhaps you must have defined your handlers in a way that they are binded to these components only on definition, not initialization.

So, if you do not declare the handler function in the `initialize` method of the components which you add/remove frequently.

Says your components are buttons, so your definition files should look like this:

```
Ext.define('mybutton',{
    extend: 'Ext.Button',
    config: {
        text: 'my button'
    },
    initialize: function(){
        var me = this;
        this.addListener({
            fn: me.doSmt,
            event: 'tap'
        });
    }
    doSmt: function(){
        // implement your logics here.......
    }
});
```